# Web based ruby on rails git deploy tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment

I'm looking for a web based ruby on rails git deploy tool for a debian server. I'm looking for something else than capistrano/webistrano.

Any suggestions?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be enough to just make a cron job that automates and then checks out what you need with the help of working-dir setting.

Hope this helps

Comment: That sounds good do you have any examples? I could also write a ruby file that executes some commands?!

Comment: I don't do it, but it should be trivial to implement. every minute, git pull the branch, if there is nothing new, nothing happens to the working dir.